# I am not able to configure jdk 10 in intellij, error message is "cannot find JDK classes in C:/program files/java/jdk"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

1. error message is "cannot find JDK classes in C:/program files/java/jdk".
2. I have tried installing other versions of JDK but it did not work.

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: intellij - 2018.1.5, windows 10

Comment: Can you please go to `File > Projct Structure.. > Platform Setting > SDKs` and check which version you are adding ?

Comment: I am adding jdk 10.0.1

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: [IntelliJ Support Question](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000040970-Cannot-find-JDK-classes)

Comment: Go to `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart ...` and then try again

Comment: It worked after invalidating Cache. Thanks for your input :)